# Integrate Pyspark Structured Streaming with confluent-kafka

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

i want to create custom data transformation on pyspark structured streaming.

I want to serialize my message into protobuf using `confluent-kafka` library. I need this library in order to integrate with SchemaRegistry. I saw they already has complete Class and Function to Serialize and Deserialize protobuf format.

Then, i was unable to use it even if i created spark udf like below :

```
def row_to_protobuf(iterator, schema_registry_url, topic):
    schema_registry_client, serializer = generate_confluent_context(schema_registry_url)
    for row in iterator:
        message = MyMessage()
        message.timestamp = int(row.timestamp)
        for key, value in row.repeated.items():
            message.repeated[str(key)] = str(value)
        value = integrate_to_confluent_proto(message, topic, serializer)
        yield value

process_to_proto_udf = f.pandas_udf(lambda x: row_to_protobuf(
        x, schema_registry_url, destination_topic), StringType())
    df = df.withColumn("value", process_to_proto_udf(f.col("value")))
```

but i got this error

```
TypeError: Return type of the user-defined function should be Pandas.Series, but is <class 'generator'>
```

Back then, if i saw confluent-kafka repository, they have custom producer class (https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/src/confluent_kafka/serializing_producer.py). So can we use this producer instead of pyspark default producer? I know that spark have kafka producer and we can use something like below

```
df.write \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", destination_server) \
  .option("topic", destination_topic) \
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_dir) \
  .mode("append") \
  .save()
```

If you have any idea or recommendation, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share your integrate function? Also, you probably should pass the topic column into UDF as well rather than use a separate variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the Spark documentation, the value column must be binary or string schema type, however Protobuf is binary, so don't use `StringType` for your UDF. If you meet that requirement, the producer will work , yes. Alternatively, you could also just use the Confluent library directly and skip the overhead of the Spark JVM and cluster management.

As far as your error goes, you'll not want to use `yield` for a pandas UDF; it wants you to return a Series. Perhaps you wanted to use a regular pyspark UDF?

Comment: Yes, i changed the code yesterday to resolve Type and move into regular pyspark udf. The function works right now. But i have another issue on connecting the result to kafka connect. may be i will post another question on it. The issue is more on the `magic byte` that need to be generated from `SerializingProducer` class on `confluent-kafka` library.

Comment: You shouldn't be using SerializingProducer  anyway when you can import the ProtobufSerializer directly